# Difference(s) between merge() and concat() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

**What's the essential difference(s) between `pd.DataFrame.merge()` and `pd.concat()`?**

So far, this is what I found, please comment on how complete and accurate my understanding is:

- `.merge()` can only use columns (plus row-indices) and it is semantically suitable for database-style operations. `.concat()` can be used with either axis, using only indices, and gives the option for adding a hierarchical index.
- Incidentally, this allows for the following redundancy: both can combine two dataframes using the rows indices.
- `pd.DataFrame.join()` merely offers a shorthand for a subset of the use cases of `.merge()`

(Pandas is great at addressing a very wide spectrum of use cases in data analysis. It can be a bit daunting exploring the documentation to figure out what is the best way to perform a particular task. )

Comment: Also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37891437/1972495 a discussion around ````.merge()```` and ````.join()````.

Comment: On merge, join and concat, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40468090/4178189) answer to be very clear on how they all can be used to do the same stuff (they seem to be just alternative interface to same functionality). Thanks to your question (and the answer you link in the comment) I know finally understand how merge and join are related. Still unclear to me if concat uses a different implementation or not (I guess I will have to look at source code...)

Answer (score 110):

A very high level difference is that `merge()` is used to combine two (or more) dataframes on the basis of values of common columns (indices can also be used, use `left_index=True` and/or `right_index=True`), and `concat()` is used to append one (or more) dataframes one below the other (or sideways, depending on whether the `axis` option is set to 0 or 1).

`join()` is used to merge 2 dataframes on the basis of the index; instead of using `merge()` with the option `left_index=True` we can use `join()`.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'], 'data1': range(7)})

df1:
   Key  data1
0   b   0
1   b   1
2   a   2
3   c   3
4   a   4
5   a   5
6   b   6

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['a', 'b', 'd'], 'data2': range(3)})

df2:
    Key data2
0   a   0
1   b   1
2   d   2

#Merge
# The 2 dataframes are merged on the basis of values in column "Key" as it is 
# a common column in 2 dataframes

pd.merge(df1, df2)

   Key data1 data2
0   b    0    1
1   b    1    1
2   b    6    1
3   a    2    0
4   a    4    0
5   a    5    0

#Concat
# df2 dataframe is appended at the bottom of df1 

pd.concat([df1, df2])

   Key data1 data2
0   b   0     NaN
1   b   1     NaN
2   a   2     NaN
3   c   3     NaN
4   a   4     NaN
5   a   5     NaN
6   b   6     NaN
0   a   Nan   0
1   b   Nan   1
2   d   Nan   2
```

Comment: So, this means that the argument `how` in `merge` works and mean totally different than what it does in `concat`?

Comment: "concat() is used to append one (or more) dataframes one below the other (or sideways, depending on whether the axis option is set to 0 or 1)." That's not true. When using concat with `axis=1` you are performing either an outer or inner join on the index. See the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes

Comment: "`merge()` is used to combine two **(or more)** dataframes" ... This is news to me. How can I `merge()` three or more dataframes without nesting multiple `merge()` calls?

Answer (score 44):

At a high level:

- `.concat()` simply stacks multiple `DataFrame` together either
  vertically, or stitches horizontally after aligning on index
- `.merge()` first aligns two `DataFrame`' selected common column(s) or
  index, and then pick up the remaining columns from the aligned rows of each `DataFrame`.

More specifically, `.concat()`:

- Is a top-level pandas function
- Combines two or more pandas `DataFrame` **vertically** or horizontally
- Aligns **only on the index** when combining horizontally
- Errors when any of the `DataFrame` contains a duplicate index.
- Defaults to outer join with the option for inner join

And `.merge()`:

- Exists both as a top-level pandas function and a `DataFrame` method (as of pandas 1.0)
- Combines exactly two `DataFrame` horizontally
- Aligns the calling `DataFrame`'s column(s) or index with the other
  `DataFrame`'s column(s) or index
- Handles **duplicate values on the joining columns or index** by
  performing a cartesian product
- Defaults to inner join with options for left, outer, and right

Note that when performing `pd.merge(left, right)`, if `left` has two rows containing the same values from the joining columns or index, each row will combine with `right`'s corresponding row(s) resulting in a cartesian product. On the other hand, if `.concat()` is used to combine columns, we need to make sure no duplicated index exists in either `DataFrame`.

**Practically speaking:**

- Consider `.concat()` first when combining homogeneous `DataFrame`, while
  consider `.merge()` first when combining complementary `DataFrame`.
- If need to merge vertically, go with `.concat()`. If need to merge
  horizontally via columns, go with `.merge()`, which by default merge on the columns in common.

Reference: [Pandas 1.x Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0851DDM7D)

Answer (score 15):

`pd.concat` takes an `Iterable` as its argument. Hence,  it cannot take `DataFrame`s directly as its argument. Also `Dimension`s of the `DataFrame` should match along axis while concatenating.

`pd.merge` can take `DataFrame`s as its argument, and is used to combine two `DataFrame`s with same columns or index, which can't be done with `pd.concat` since it will show the repeated column in the DataFrame.

Whereas join can be used to join two `DataFrame`s with different indices.

Comment: I like this answer because it states the dimensions should match when concatenating. `concat` is nothing more than glueing several dataframes on top of/next to eachother. It is not content aware in the sense that it will just show the same column twice. Whereas `merge` will actually *merge* columns when they are the same.

Comment: I think it's not true. Even the answer above (by @Abhishek Sawant) gives an example of `concat` where dimensions do not match.

Answer (score 10):

> I am currently trying to understand the essential difference(s) between `pd.DataFrame.merge()` and `pd.concat()`.

Nice question. The main difference:

#### [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) works on both axes.

The other difference, is `pd.concat` has ***inner***<sup><sup>**default**</sup></sup> and ***outer*** joins only, while [`pd.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has ***left***, ***right***, ***outer***, ***inner***<sup><sup>**default**</sup></sup> joins.

Third notable other difference is: `pd.DataFrame.merge()` has the option to set the column suffixes when merging columns with the same name, while for `pd.concat` this is not possible.

---

With `pd.concat` by default you are able to stack rows of multiple dataframes (`axis=0`) and when you set the `axis=1` then you mimic the `pd.DataFrame.merge()` function.

Some useful examples of `pd.concat`:

```
df2=pd.concat([df]*2, ignore_index=True) #double the rows of a dataframe

df2=pd.concat([df, df.iloc[[0]]]) # add first row to the end

df3=pd.concat([df1,df2], join='inner', ignore_index=True) # concat two df's
```

Comment: In `pd.concat`, outer join is default.    

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 6):

The main difference between merge & concat is that merge allow you to perform more structured "join" of tables where use of concat is more broad and less structured.

**Merge**

Referring the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), `pd.DataFrame.merge` takes *right* as a required argument, which you can think it as joining left table and right table according to some pre-defined structured join operation. Note the definition for parameter *right*.

***Required Parameters***

- *right*: DataFrame or named Series

***Optional Parameters***

- *how*: {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’} default ‘inner’
- *on*: label or list
- *left_on*: label or list, or array-like
- *right_on*: label or list, or array-like
- *left_index*: bool, default False
- *right_index*: bool, default False
- *sort*: bool, default False
- *suffixes*: tuple of (str, str), default (‘_x’, ‘_y’)
- *copy*: bool, default True
- *indicator*: bool or str, default False
- *validate*: str, optional

**Important:** `pd.DataFrame.merge` requires right to be a `pd.DataFrame` or named `pd.Series` object.

**Output**

- *Returns*: DataFrame

Furthermore, if we check the docstring for Merge Operation on pandas is below:

> Perform a database (SQL) merge operation between two DataFrame or Series
>       objects using either columns as keys or their row indexes

**Concat**

Refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) of `pd.concat`, first note that the parameter is not named any of *table, data_frame, series, matrix*, etc., but *objs* instead. That is, you can pass many "data containers", which are defined as:

`Iterable[FrameOrSeriesUnion], Mapping[Optional[Hashable], FrameOrSeriesUnion]`

**Required Parameters**

- *objs*: a sequence or mapping of Series or DataFrame objects

***Optional Parameters***

- *axis*: {0/’index’, 1/’columns’}, default 0
- *join*: {‘inner’, ‘outer’}, default ‘outer’
- *ignore_index*: bool, default False
- *keys*: sequence, default None
- *levels*: list of sequences, default None
- *names*: list, default None
- *verify_integrity*: bool, default False
- *sort*: bool, default False
- *copy*: bool, default True

***Output***

- *Returns*: object, type of objs

**Example**

***Code***

```
import pandas as pd

v1 = pd.Series([1, 5, 9, 13])
v2 = pd.Series([10, 100, 1000, 10000])
v3 = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3])

df_left = pd.DataFrame({
    "v1": v1,
    "v2": v2,
    "v3": v3
    })
df_right = pd.DataFrame({
    "v4": [5, 5, 5, 5],
    "v5": [3, 2, 1, 0]
    })


df_concat = pd.concat([v1, v2, v3])

# Performing operations on default

merge_result = df_left.merge(df_right, left_index=True, right_index=True)
concat_result = pd.concat([df_left, df_right], sort=False)
print(merge_result)
print('='*20)
print(concat_result)
```

***Code Output***

```
   v1     v2  v3  v4  v5
0   1     10   0   5   3
1   5    100   1   5   2
2   9   1000   2   5   1
3  13  10000   3   5   0
====================
     v1       v2   v3   v4   v5
0   1.0     10.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1   5.0    100.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2   9.0   1000.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
3  13.0  10000.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
0   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0
1   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
2   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  1.0
```

You can achieve, however, the first output (merge) with concat by changing the *axis* parameter

```
concat_result = pd.concat([df_left, df_right], sort=False, axis=1)
```

Observe the following behavior,

```
concat_result = pd.concat([df_left, df_right, df_left, df_right], sort=False)
```

outputs;

```
     v1       v2   v3   v4   v5
0   1.0     10.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1   5.0    100.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2   9.0   1000.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
3  13.0  10000.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
0   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0
1   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
2   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  1.0
3   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  0.0
0   1.0     10.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1   5.0    100.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2   9.0   1000.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
3  13.0  10000.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
0   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  3.0
1   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  2.0
2   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  1.0
3   NaN      NaN  NaN  5.0  0.0
```

, which you cannot perform a similar operation with merge, since it only allows a single DataFrame or named Series.

```
merge_result = df_left.merge([df_right, df_left, df_right], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

outputs;

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed
```

**Conclusion**

As you may have notice already that input and outputs may be different between "merge" and "concat".

**As I mentioned at the beginning, the very first (main) difference is that "merge" performs a more structured join with a set of restricted set of objects and parameters where as "concat" performs a less strict/broader join with a broader set of objects and parameters.**

All in all, merge is less tolerant to changes/(the input) and "concat" is looser/less sensitive to changes/(the input). ***You can achieve "merge" by using "concat", but the reverse is not always true.***

"Merge" operation uses Data Frame columns (or name of `pd.Series` object) or row indices, and since it uses those entities only it performs horizontal merge of Data Frames or Series, and does not apply vertical operation as a result.

If you want to see more, you can deep dive in the source code a bit;

- Source code for [concat](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py#L65-L284)
- Source code for [merge](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L7265-L7298)

Answer (score 0):

The `concat` method is exactly what the `UNION ALL` operator does in `SQL`. In `Pandas`, you can `UNION ALL` your dataframes not only along the index axis (as in `SQL`), but also along the column axis (if you concat two dataframes of 3 columns each, you get a new dataframe of 6 columns). The `join` and `merge` methods are the same as `JOIN` in `SQL`, although the latter is more powerful and is the most commonly used.

Answer (score -1):

Only concat function has axis parameter. Merge is used to combine dataframes side-by-side based on values in shared columns so there is no need for axis parameter.

Answer (score -2):

by default:
    join is a column-wise left join
    pd.merge is a column-wise inner join
    pd.concat is a row-wise outer join

pd.concat:
    takes Iterable arguments. Thus, it cannot take DataFrames directly (use [df,df2])
    Dimensions of DataFrame should match along axis

Join and pd.merge:
    can take DataFrame arguments

[Click to see picture for understanding why code below does the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UceSa.png)

```
df1.join(df2)
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```