# Merge two dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have the following dataframes:

```
> df1
  id  begin conditional confidence discoveryTechnique  
0 278    56       false        0.0                  1   
1 421    18       false        0.0                  1 

> df2
   concept 
0  A  
1  B
```

How do I merge on the indices to get:

```
  id  begin conditional confidence discoveryTechnique concept 
0 278    56       false        0.0                  1       A 
1 421    18       false        0.0                  1       B
```

I ask because it is my understanding that `merge()` i.e. `df1.merge(df2)` uses columns to do the matching. In fact, doing this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4618, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 58, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 491, in __init__
    self._validate_specification()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 812, in _validate_specification
    raise MergeError('No common columns to perform merge on')
pandas.tools.merge.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on
```

Is it bad practice to merge on index? Is it impossible? If so, how can I shift the index into a new column called "index"?

Comment: try this: `df1.join(df2)`

Comment: What if you want to join by the index of one dataframe and a column of the second dataframe. (My second dataframe has a column that matches up with the indeces in the first df.)

Answer (score 653, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), which is an inner join by default:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Or [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), which is a left join by default:

```
df1.join(df2)
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), which is an outer join by default:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

**Samples**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(6),
                    'b':[5,3,6,9,2,4]}, index=list('abcdef'))

print (df1)
   a  b
a  0  5
b  1  3
c  2  6
d  3  9
e  4  2
f  5  4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':range(4),
                    'd':[10,20,30, 40]}, index=list('abhi'))

print (df2)
   c   d
a  0  10
b  1  20
h  2  30
i  3  40
```

---

```
# Default inner join
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df3)
   a  b  c   d
a  0  5  0  10
b  1  3  1  20

# Default left join
df4 = df1.join(df2)
print (df4)
   a  b    c     d
a  0  5  0.0  10.0
b  1  3  1.0  20.0
c  2  6  NaN   NaN
d  3  9  NaN   NaN
e  4  2  NaN   NaN
f  5  4  NaN   NaN

# Default outer join
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df5)
     a    b    c     d
a  0.0  5.0  0.0  10.0
b  1.0  3.0  1.0  20.0
c  2.0  6.0  NaN   NaN
d  3.0  9.0  NaN   NaN
e  4.0  2.0  NaN   NaN
f  5.0  4.0  NaN   NaN
h  NaN  NaN  2.0  30.0
i  NaN  NaN  3.0  40.0
```

Answer (score 48):

You can use [concat([df1, df2, ...], axis=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) in order to concatenate two or more DFs aligned by indexes:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, ...], axis=1)
```

Or [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for concatenating by custom fields / indexes:

```
# join by _common_ columns: `col1`, `col3`
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['col1','col3'])

# join by: `df1.col1 == df2.index`
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1' right_index=True)
```

or [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for joining by index:

```
 df1.join(df2)
```

Answer (score 17):

> This answer has been resolved for a while and all the available
> options are already out there. However in this answer I'll attempt to
> shed a bit more light on these options to help you understand when to
> use what.

This post will go through the following topics:

- Merging with index under different conditions

  - options for index-based joins: `merge`, `join`, `concat`
  - merging on indexes
  - merging on index of one, column of other
- effectively using named indexes to simplify merging syntax

---

## Index-based joins

#### TL;DR

> There are a few options, some simpler than others depending on the use
> case.
>
> 1. [**`DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left_index` and `right_index` (or `left_on` and `right_on` using named indexes)
> 2. [**`DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (joins on index)
> 3. [**`pd.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (joins on index)

|  | PROS | CONS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `merge` | • supports inner/left/right/full • supports column-column, index-column, index-index joins | • can only join two frames at a time |
| `join` | • supports inner/left (default)/right/full • can join multiple DataFrames at a time | • only supports index-index joins |
| `concat` | • specializes in joining multiple DataFrames at a time • very fast (concatenation is linear time) | • only supports inner/full (default) joins • only supports index-index joins |

---

#### Index to index joins

Typically, an **inner join on index** would look like this:

```
left.merge(right, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Other types of joins (left, right, outer) follow similar syntax (and can be controlled using `how=...`).

**Notable Alternatives**

1. **[`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)** defaults to a left outer join on the index.

   ```
    left.join(right, how='inner',)
   ```

   If you happen to get `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified`, you will need to specify `lsuffix` and `rsuffix=` arguments to resolve this. Since the column names are same, a differentiating suffix is required.
2. **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)** joins on the index and can join two or more DataFrames at once. It does a full outer join by default.

   ```
    pd.concat([left, right], axis=1, sort=False)
   ```

   For more information on `concat`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio/49620539#49620539).

---

#### **Index to Column joins**

To perform an inner join using index of left, column of right, you will use `DataFrame.merge` a combination of `left_index=True` and `right_on=...`.

```
left.merge(right, left_index=True, right_on='key')
```

Other joins follow a similar structure. Note that **only** `merge` can perform index to column joins. You can join on multiple levels/columns, provided the number of index levels on the left equals the number of columns on the right.

`join` and `concat` are not capable of mixed merges. You will need to set the index as a pre-step using [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

---

<sup>This post is an abridged version of my work in [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/4909087). Please follow this link for more examples and other topics on merging.</sup>

Answer (score 16):

By default:
    `join` is a column-wise left join
    `pd.merge` is a column-wise inner join
    `pd.concat` is a row-wise outer join

`pd.concat`:
    takes Iterable arguments. Thus, it cannot take DataFrames directly (use `[df,df2]`)
    Dimensions of DataFrame should match along axis

`Join` and `pd.merge`:
    can take DataFrame arguments

Answer (score 13):

A silly bug that got me: the joins failed because index `dtypes` differed. This was not obvious as both tables were pivot tables of the same original table. After `reset_index`, the indices looked identical in [Jupyter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook). It only came to light when saving to Excel...

I fixed it with: `df1[['key']] = df1[['key']].apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Hopefully this saves somebody an hour!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to join two dataframes in Pandas, you can simply use available attributes like `merge` or `concatenate`.

For example, if I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`, I can join them by:

```
newdataframe = merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: This answer was already provided 2 years ago by jezrael. Why are you posting the same answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can try these few ways to merge/join your `dataframe`.

1. `merge` (inner join by default)

   `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`
2. `join` (left join by default)

   `df = df1.join(df2)`
3. `concat` (outer join by default)

   `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`