# Join two Dataframe table

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe table :

df1

```
id A
1  wer
3  dfg
5  dfg
```

df2

```
id A
2  fgv
4  sdfsdf
```

I want to join this to dataframe for one that will look like that:

df3

```
id A
1 wer
2 fgv
3 dfg
```

...

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/python-pandas-merge-two-dataframes-by-index

Comment: That's some quite bad examples... what happens after 3 .... -1

Answer (score 0):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',sort=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) method in pandas that you can use.

`df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])`

You can sort index with -

`df3 = df3.sort_index()`

Or reset index like

`df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)`

I see you have ellipsis (...) at the end of your df3 dataframe if that means continuation in dataframe use above otherwise go for [Jibril's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051303/5406448)