# collecting data from dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas

I got a DataFrame called base like the following

```
number   act
12       yes
33       zero
24       cool
53       loop
```

and another DataFrame called info like:

```
source   name    age
12       ashe    23
4        man     45
23       mark    12
33       john    34
```

I need to do the following, ‍‍‍‍‍`if base["number"] == info["source"]`, I want to create a new DataFrame be like:

```
number   name   age  
12       ashe   23
33       john   34
```

what can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index)

Comment: no, see my edit, the key isn't the same in both DataFrame