# Merge one row of a dataframe to another dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes,

1) df1

```
    JobId   WorkOrderNo   TradeName TradeMasterId   LateNight   Weekends    Weekdays
53  10165   samsung10165    Carpenter   1090          False       False      True
54  10166   samsung10166    None        1090          False       False      True
55  10167   samsung10167    None        1090          True        False      False
56  10168   samsung10168    None        1090          False       True       False
57  10169   samsung10169    None        1090          True        True       True
```

2) df2

```
     JobId   Score    TradeName    TradeMasterId    LateNight   Weekends    Weekdays    TechnicianId    
10  10167   0.771517    None        1090              True        False       False         1325    
4   10166   0.771517    None        1090              False       False       True          1296    
1   10168   0.771517    None        1090              False       True        False         1357    
16  10161   0.524142    Carpenter   1090              False       False       True          1296    
23  10156   0.520266    Carpenter   1090              True        True        False         1332    
32  10162   0.462910    Carpenter   1090              True        False       False         1296    
33  10165   0.455842    Carpenter   1090              False       False       True          1337    
42  10164   0.428571    Carpenter   1090              False       False       True          1296
```

So the df2's columns 'LateNight', 'Weekends', 'Weekdays' matches with df1's JobId = '10165' s columns 'Latenight', 'Weekends', 'Weekdays',

The final result should be like this,

Finaldf

```
     JobId   Score    TradeName    TradeMasterId    LateNight   Weekends    Weekdays    TechnicianId      
4   10166   0.771517    None        1090              False       False       True          1296     
16  10161   0.524142    Carpenter   1090              False       False       True          1296      
32  10162   0.462910    Carpenter   1090              True        False       True          1296      
42  10164   0.428571    Carpenter   1090              False       False       True          1296
56  10165   0.345672    Carpenter   1090              True        True        True          1296
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: so you only want to keep the rows that are apparent in both dfs? Have you tried a inner merge? If not you could try something like: `Finaldf = df2.merge(df1, on=['JobId', 'TradeName',    'TradeMasterId', 'Weekends', 'Weekdays'], how='inner')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index)