# find date in data frame and append the data to a different data frame PYTHON

Tags: python, dataframe

I need your help. I have 2 DataFrame, Table A and Table B. I need to find the date that is in Table A in Table B and add a column with the values of the VALUE2 AND VALUE3 columns, leaving VALUE 1 behind. The output is Table C.

I mean there are many columns

Table A

```
DATE           NAME    EDAD  
2019-07-18      KAT     12     
2019-07-19      FEP     13
```

Table B

```
DATE          VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
2019-07-16      10      20     30
2019-07-17      11      22     33
2019-07-18      10      20     30
2019-07-19      11      22     33
```

Table C

```
DATE           NAME    EDAD  VALUE2 VALUE3
2019-07-18      KAT     12     20     30
2019-07-19      FEP     13     22     33

thanks!
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html start here, you will find your way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index)

Comment: No, I need to find the date and give me the data corresponding to that date

Comment: `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` 
try this code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df1.merge(df2,on='DATE', how='left')[['DATE','NAME','EDAD','VALUE2','VALUE3']]
```

df1 is Table A and df2 is Table B

Prints:

```
         DATE NAME  EDAD  VALUE2  VALUE3
0  2019-07-18  KAT    12      20      30
1  2019-07-19  FEP    13      22      33
```

Comment: what happens when the columns have different names in the date column?

Comment: @Katherine please read the documentation link I sent you.