# Add the string from one dataframe in a new column of a second dataframe while comparing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to check if a value from a column in one dataframe exists in a column of second dataframe. If it exists then add that value in a new column of the same row in second dataframe. All the values are string values. Both the dataframes are of different size. Also second dataframe has around 700K records. So the dataframes I have:

DF1

```
THINGS
book+pen
CAR 
chair
laptop
```

DF2

```
Description
I want a new book.
I will pen down this things 
A quick ride in my new car.
Cars are awesome.
My laptop's memory is bad.
Maybe try sitting on that CHAIR.
```

The output I want that is addition of an 'Updated' column:

```
Description                        Updated
I want a new book.                 book
I will pen down this things        pen
A quick ride in my new car.        car
Cars are awesome.                  car
My laptop's memory is bad.         laptop
Maybe try sitting on that CHAIR.   chair
Search for that book in my laptop. book+laptop
```

I have tried the brute method but its taking too long to process. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have range-index you can just merge on the index if not you can `df.reset_index()` `df2.reset_index()` and then just `pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` also for more info on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

1. Used `str.split` and `explode` to first get a neat list of strings to match from df1
2. Created two columns with all lower cases for case insensitive match.
3. used `str.findall` to retrieve the matched strings between dfs.
4. Stripped of the paranthesis and quotes using `str.strip`

Code:

```
df1 = df1.assign(THINGS=df1['THINGS'].str.split('+')).explode('THINGS')
df1['THINGS2'] = df1.THINGS.str.lower()
df2['Description2'] =  df2.Description.str.lower()
df2['Updated'] = df2.Description2.str.findall('|'.join(df1.THINGS2))
df2['Updated'] = df2.Updated.astype(str).str.strip(to_strip=r'''[|]|\'''')
del df2['Description2']
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
                        Description Updated
0                I want a new book.    book
1      I will pen down this things      pen
2       A quick ride in my new car.     car
3                 Cars are awesome.     car
4           My laptops hangs a lot.  laptop
5  Maybe try sitting on that CHAIR.   chair
```

Comment: @yellow_smile did it help?

Comment: No just getting empty string from this code : df2['Updated'] = df2.Description2.str.findall('|'.join(df1.THINGS2))

Comment: Hmm.. are you testing it on the dataset you provided? Are all rows blank for 'updated' column? I just tested and it worked again!.

Comment: Yes the same data and yeah all rows are blank idk why

Comment: tats strange.. I just copied the dataset that you pasted as it is.. Is explode working fine? Did you try printing df1 ?

Comment: Actually it gives error when there are multiple 'things' in an 'Item Description'.