# How to pair two Data frames based on their index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two DataFrames (df1, df2), both with a DateTime index type:

```
print(type(df1.index))  =>  pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
print(type(df2.index))  =>  pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

Both have just one column with some values:

print(df1):

```
Sample Date  Value df1     
1992-01-02   430.0
1992-01-03   436.0
1992-01-04   439.0
1992-01-05   432.0
1992-01-06   427.0
           ...
2003-12-26   300.0
2003-12-27   306.0
2003-12-28   319.0
2003-12-29   321.0
2003-12-30   310.0

[4381 rows x 1 columns]
```

print(df2):

```
Sample Date   Value df2    
1992-02-12    15.0
1992-04-11    24.0
1992-09-12    14.0
1992-11-18    26.0
1992-11-25    14.0
           ...
2003-10-09    43.0
2003-10-22    12.0
2003-12-02     4.0
2003-12-03    18.0
2003-12-08    44.0

[424 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to get a new DF with those two columns (Value df1 and Value df2) just with the rows where the data is available in both data frames. For simplicity df1 is a DF without missing dates, whereas df2 has missing dates.

The results should look something like this:

```
Sample Date   Value df1    Value df2    
1992-02-12    350.5        15.0
1992-04-11    420.2        24.0
1992-09-12    400.0        14.0
1992-11-18    380.5        26.0
1992-11-25    395.9        14.0
               ...         ...
2003-10-09    500.5        43.0
2003-10-22    480.9        12.0
2003-12-02    500.8        4.0
2003-12-03    350.0        18.0
2003-12-08    370.8        44.0
```

I tried to create a new df like this:

```
df = df1[df1.index.isin([df2.index])]
```

but the result is an empty DF. If I print `df1.index.isin([df2.index])` I do get something like this: `array([False, False, False, ..., False, False, False])`.

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but it involves [DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with the `how` parameter set to `"inner"`

Comment: Thanks @Kenny! I tried it and it work. Something like this:  df1.join(df2,  how='inner')

Comment: Merge by index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index

Comment: Or: reset_index() both df.  And then merge by date column.