# Why merging 2 data frames gives me one with triple the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `df1`:

```
       x            y no.
0  -17.7    -0.785430  y1
1  -15.0 -3820.085000  y4
2  -12.5     2.138833  y3
..  ....     ........  ..
40  15.6     5.486901  y2
41  19.2     1.980686  y3
42  19.6     9.364718  y2
```

and `df2`:

```
       delta y     x
0     0.053884 -17.7
1     0.085000 -15.0
2     0.143237 -12.5
..    ........  ....
40    0.113099  15.6
41    0.102245  19.2
42    0.235282  19.6
```

They both have 43 rows, and `x` column is exactly the same on both.

Somehow when I merge them on `x` I get a df with 123 rows:

```
 x            y no.   delta y
0   -17.7    -0.785430  y1  0.053884
1   -15.0 -3820.085000  y4  0.085000
2   -12.5     2.138833  y3  0.143237
3   -12.4     1.721205  y3  0.251180
4   -12.1     2.227343  y2  0.127343
..    ...          ...  ..       ...
118  12.1     1.642526  y3  0.143886
119  14.4  2576.435000  y4  0.171000
120  15.6     5.486901  y2  0.113099
121  19.2     1.980686  y3  0.102245
122  19.6     9.364718  y2  0.235282
```

My input: `final = df1.merge(df2, on="x")`
x      float64
y      float64
no.     object
dtype: object

delta y    float64
x          float64
dtype: object

x      float64
y      float64
no.     object
dtype: object

delta y    float64
x          float64
dtype: object

x      float64
y      float64
no.     object
dtype: object

delta y    float64
x          float64
dtype: object

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': {0: -17.7, 1: -15.0, 2: -12.5, 3: -12.4, 4: -12.1, 5: -11.2, 6: -8.9, 7: -7.5, 8: -7.5, 9: -6.0, 10: -6.0, 11: -4.7, 12: -4.1, 13: -3.8, 14: -3.4, 15: -3.4, 16: -1.9, 17: -1.5, 18: -1.1, 19: -0.4, 20: -0.1, 21: 3.5, 22: 3.8, 23: 5.3, 24: 5.3, 25: 5.3, 26: 5.3, 27: 5.3, 28: 5.3, 29: 5.3, 30: 5.3, 31: 5.3, 32: 6.4, 33: 6.8, 34: 6.8, 35: 10.2, 36: 10.3, 37: 11.9, 38: 12.1, 39: 14.4, 40: 15.6, 41: 19.2, 42: 19.6}, 'y': {0: -0.7854295, 1: -3820.085, 2: 2.1388333, 3: 1.7212046, 4: 2.227343, 5: 0.04315967, 6: -0.9616607, 7: -1.9878536, 8: -0.52237016, 9: -283.27216, 10: -282.5332, 11: -0.4335017, 12: -1.1585577, 13: -0.008831219, 14: 848.92303, 15: -57.407845, 16: -9.010686, 17: -3.2473037, 18: 0.5536767, 19: 1.8351307, 20: 4.8347697, 21: -6.45842, 22: -1.5683812, 23: 0.9338831, 24: 0.9338831, 25: 97.65833, 26: 1.6500127, 27: 1.6500127, 28: 97.65833, 29: 97.65833, 30: 1.6500127, 31: 97.65833, 32: -3.655422, 33: 1.9058462, 34: 227.5592, 35: 857.7455, 36: -0.68584794, 37: 1.6785516, 38: 1.6425261, 39: 2576.435, 40: 5.4869013, 41: 1.9806856, 42: 9.364718}, 'no.': {0: 'y1', 1: 'y4', 2: 'y3', 3: 'y3', 4: 'y2', 5: 'y3', 6: 'y2', 7: 'y2', 8: 'y2', 9: 'y4', 10: 'y4', 11: 'y1', 12: 'y3', 13: 'y1', 14: 'y4', 15: 'y4', 16: 'y4', 17: 'y4', 18: 'y1', 19: 'y3', 20: 'y4', 21: 'y2', 22: 'y3', 23: 'y3', 24: 'y3', 25: 'y4', 26: 'y3', 27: 'y3', 28: 'y4', 29: 'y3', 30: 'y4', 31: 'y4', 32: 'y2', 33: 'y3', 34: 'y3', 35: 'y4', 36: 'y3', 37: 'y3', 38: 'y3', 39: 'y4', 40: 'y2', 41: 'y3', 42: 'y2'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'delta y': {0: 0.05388353000000001, 1: 0.08500000000003638, 2: 0.14323679999999994, 3: 0.25117999999999996, 4: 0.12734299999999976, 5: 0.36285006000000003, 6: 0.13833930000000005, 7: 0.5121464, 8: 1.97762984, 9: 0.2721599999999853, 10: 0.4667999999999779, 11: 0.2692114, 12: 0.00890970000000002, 13: 0.314458351, 14: 906.34703, 15: 0.0161549999999977, 16: 0.06831400000000087, 17: 0.3723036999999998, 18: 0.2988478, 19: 0.006991300000000145, 20: 0.14423030000000026, 21: 0.04157999999999973, 22: 0.013554200000000183, 23: 0.17486560000000007, 24: 0.17486560000000007, 25: 0.03866999999999621, 26: 0.541264, 27: 0.541264, 28: 0.03866999999999621, 29: 96.5495813, 30: 96.0469873, 31: 0.03866999999999621, 32: 0.05542200000000008, 33: 0.1670513, 34: 225.82040510000002, 35: 0.38250000000005, 36: 0.59580486, 37: 0.10641100000000003, 38: 0.14388610000000002, 39: 0.17099999999982174, 40: 0.11309869999999922, 41: 0.10224489999999986, 42: 0.23528199999999977}, 'x': {0: -17.7, 1: -15.0, 2: -12.5, 3: -12.4, 4: -12.1, 5: -11.2, 6: -8.9, 7: -7.5, 8: -7.5, 9: -6.0, 10: -6.0, 11: -4.7, 12: -4.1, 13: -3.8, 14: -3.4, 15: -3.4, 16: -1.9, 17: -1.5, 18: -1.1, 19: -0.4, 20: -0.1, 21: 3.5, 22: 3.8, 23: 5.3, 24: 5.3, 25: 5.3, 26: 5.3, 27: 5.3, 28: 5.3, 29: 5.3, 30: 5.3, 31: 5.3, 32: 6.4, 33: 6.8, 34: 6.8, 35: 10.2, 36: 10.3, 37: 11.9, 38: 12.1, 39: 14.4, 40: 15.6, 41: 19.2, 42: 19.6}})

`final = df1.merge(df2, on="x")`

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a running script that demonstrates the problem? You shouldn't need 47 rows, just a few should do. It would also be useful to do `df1['x'] - df2['x']` on your existing data to make sure they are equal.

Comment: I did `df1['x'] - df2['x']` and all  values are 0.0. Can you explain me what you mean by "posting a running script?" I'm kinda new to programming and to this website

Comment: I cleaned up your your examples by getting rid of the .... row, initialized the dataframes and then did the merge. It worked for me. But that was a bit of work. You could trim down df1 and df2 to something smaller that still fails. To make a working example, you could do `df1.to_dict()` then paste that result into a test script where you do `df1 = pd.DataFrame( ... paste dict here ...)`. Then the same with `df2`. Then add the merge to the script. Now it runs, demonstrates the problem, and we can grab the result ourselves to test.

Comment: @tdelaney I even used 20 decimals and in all values I get 0.00000000000000000000

Comment: You could do ` (df1['x'] - df2['x']).any()` but it sounds like they are the same. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you also post `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes`? See if there is any difference.

Comment: @tdelaney yeah it is impossible that the numbers are different beyond that decimal, give me a moment to see if I can extract some info

Comment: @tdelaney I edited the post. Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that x values aren't unique. If the 2 x columns are identical and you haven't done anything to change the indexes of df1 and df2, you could just add the wanted column `df1["delta y"] = df2["delta y"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `x` values are not unique, so the merge duplicates rows to get all of the combinations. In a simple example

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,2], "b":['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,2], "c":['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']})
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='a')
   a  b   c
0  1  a  aa
1  2  b  bb
2  2  b  dd
3  2  d  bb
4  2  d  dd
5  3  c  cc
```

`2` is not unique in the column and gets all of the combinations (notice b --> dd and d --> dd).

In your case, the `x` column is identical in the two dataframes. This would also mean that indexes haven't changed and you could assign the columns you want to `df1`.

```
df1["delta y"] = df2["delta y"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following: `df1.join(df2)`

join is a column-wise left join

pd.merge is a column-wise inner join

pd.concat is a row-wise outer join

pd.concat:
takes Iterable arguments. Thus, it cannot take DataFrames directly (use [df,df2])
Dimensions of DataFrame should match along axis

Join and pd.merge:
can take DataFrame arguments

ref: [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index)

Comment: Gives me this "raise ValueError(f"columns overlap but no suffix specified: {to_rename}")
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['x'], dtype='object') "

Comment: try df1.join(df2, on='x', how='left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right') or try pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

Comment: The last one (concat) worked but now i have duplicate `x `columns. One as the 1st column and the other as the last. It's no problem, i can just remove one, just wondering why it happened

Comment: add inner join as an argument in function

Comment: Can you please explain, I'm new in Python. I did this `final = pd.concat([df1, df2], how="inner", axis=1)`but It is obviously wrong

Comment: check the documentation for function arguments, "how" is not an argument in pd.concat function link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: I tried `final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")`. Same result

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax and I encourage you to thoroughly read the official documentation of python, the link is given at the bottom.
I think you might have different x values in df1 and df2 and they are not 100% identical. This could be perhaps because of the decimals.

```
import pandas as pd

left = pd.DataFrame(
   {
       "key": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
     }
 )


right = pd.DataFrame(
     {
        "key": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
         "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
         "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
     }
 )
 

result = pd.merge(left, right, on="key")
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQJ4f.png)

[Python Merge,Join, Concatenate Official Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Hi. Thank you! I will read it when I'm done with this project (deadline soon). But how come I have different x values when this column was untouched the whole program?

Comment: @PeterM you could do `df1['x'] - df2['x']` to see if any are non-zero. We don't see your code so don't know whether these _should_ be the same or not. But there can be subtle differences, for instance one `float16` and the other `float64`.