# print a second df by pulling the same values from two different df columns that do not match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, subset

I have two different unmatch (columns&rows) data frame, actually one of these df is a subset of the other df. also we can call main and subset dfs. And I want to find matched values between subset and main df. Then I need to add the matched value from main df to subset df.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTG1z.png) -- > also you can examine my example table
For example:

```
>>dfa
Col1  Col2
1     0,01
2     0.002
3     0.02
4     0.003
5     0.004
6     0.005
7     0.008
>>dfs
Col1  Col2  
1     0,01  
2     0.002
3     0.02
4     0.004
> output
Col1  Col2    Col2
1     0,01    0,01 
2     0.002   0.002
3     0.02    0.02
4     0.003   NaN
5     0.004   0.004
6     0.005   NaN
7     0.008   NaN
```

In this example dfs is subset of dfa. and I want to find only same values from Col2 and add to dfs for new column.

Thanks all.

Comment: can you show what you want `dfs` to look like after adding the column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index)

Comment: actually concat method is useful but I have a second step that I should write same value to subset df from dfa.