# Filter a dataframe with datetime index using another dataframe with date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, datetimeindex

I have two dataframes, one dataframe has index with date and  time, the other dataframe's index only has date. Now I'd like to filter rows of first dataframe if its date is within 2nd dataframe's index.

I can do it but very complicated to use two for loop to check each item. Is there a simple way?

Here is what I did:

First dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df.index=['2022-01-01 10:00','2022-01-02 13:00','2022-01-07 10:00','2022-01-08 10:00','2022-01-11 10:00','2022-01-12 10:00']
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df

    value
2022-01-01 10:00:00 1
2022-01-02 13:00:00 2
2022-01-07 10:00:00 3
2022-01-08 10:00:00 4
2022-01-11 10:00:00 5
2022-01-12 10:00:00 6
```

2nd dataframe

```
f_1=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3]})
df_1.index=['2022-01-02','2022-01-05','2022-01-07']
df_1.index=pd.to_datetime(df_1.index)
df_1

    value
2022-01-02  1
2022-01-05  2
2022-01-07  3
```

Now I am checking each element of first dataframe's index is equal to any element of 2nd dataframe's index. If so, then save value of True

```
date_same=[False]*len(df.index)
for ix,date1 in enumerate(df.index.date):
    for date2 in df_1.index:
        if date1==date2:
            date_same[ix]=True
            break
date_same   

[False, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Now using saved list to filter the first dataframe

```
df_filter=df.loc[date_same]
df_filter

    value
2022-01-02 13:00:00 2
2022-01-07 10:00:00 3
```

Comment: Try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468069/merge-two-dataframes-by-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `np.isin` to create a boolean array and index it:

```py
df.loc[np.isin(df.index.date, df_1.index.date)]
```

[image: res]

Comment: Hi cottontail, how to get row index of this filtered dataframe within the original dataframe? Thanks

Comment: I meant row index like which row in the original dataframe, for example, in the above example,  the filtered dataframe is from the 2nd row and 3rd row of the original dataframe, so I am expecting [1,2].  I think I found it now by doing [df.index.get_loc(a) for a in df_filtered.index]. Thanks

Comment: @roudan does assigning a new column before filtering work? `df.assign(idx=np.arange(len(df))).loc[np.isin(df.index.date, df_1.index.date)]`