# merge two csv files via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

This is part of my first file:

```
>NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10 301022  fa_10   PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain
>NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104 301022  fa_11   PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain
>NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20  301022  fa_11   PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain
```

This is part of my second file:

```
>NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10 gb|AVX77188.1|  67.177  724 719 236 0   0.0 1017
>NODE_102_length_146227_cov_1.193242_34 gb|AGD14055.1|;gb|QCA67811.1|;gb|QCA68885.1|;gb|QCA71791.1|;gb|AUF68592.1|; 49.512;40.618;40.047;41.734;38.038; 454;454;454;454;454; 410;421;422;369;418; 207;221;224;199;231; 0;10;10;8;8; 3.71e-159;1.64e-77;7.99e-76;4.89e-74;6.11e-70; 461;252;248;243;232;
>NODE_1045_length_25717_cov_0.952104_13 gb|AEI19864.1|;gb|QHZ14374.1|;gb|QFN56428.1|;gb|AYH98249.1|;gb|AYH98253.1|; 56.442;53.420;53.420;53.420;53.094; 372;372;372;372;372; 326;307;307;307;307; 140;142;142;142;143; 1;1;1;1;1;
>NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104 gb|AGX66494.1|;gb|ADS15792.1|;gb|AKW57899.1|;gb|ACH26137.1|;gb|AGX66492.1|; 85.078;54.852;45.781;44.040;43.114; 518;518;518;518;518; 516;474;474;495;501; 77;204;231;246;258; 0;4;9;11;9; 0.0;0.0;1.47e-139;5.50e-138;1.69e-137; 928;557;416;413;411;
```

I need to merge these files by 'id'.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1', sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2', sep='\t')

df1.columns = ['id', 'sample', 'bin', 'profile']
df2.columns = ['id', 'sub id', 'identity', 'q length', 'alignment length', 'mismatches', 'gap opens', 'evalue', 'bit score'] 

print(df1.head(3))

id  sample    bin                                 profile
0   >NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10  301022  fa_10  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain
1   >NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104  301022  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain
2    >NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20  301022  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain

print(df2.head(3))

id          sub id  ...  evalue  bit score
0             >NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10  gb|AVX77188.1|  ...     0.0     1017.0
1   >NODE_102_length_146227_cov_1.193242_34 gb|AGD...             NaN  ...     NaN        NaN
2   >NODE_1045_length_25717_cov_0.952104_13 gb|AEI...             NaN
```

I tried these two ways:

```
# **First way**
df1.set_index(['id'])
df2.set_index(['id'])
newdf = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='id')
newdf.to_csv('out.txt', index=False)  

# **Second way**

df1[['sub id', 'identity', 'q length', 'alignment length', 'mismatches', 'gap opens', 'evalue', 'bit score']] = df2[['sub id', 'identity', 'q length', 'alignment length', 'mismatches', 'gap opens', 'evalue', 'bit score']]

df1.to_csv('out2.txt', index=False)
```

Resulting out.txt and out2.txt are the same:

```
>NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_102,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_60_length_195775_cov_1.016241_138,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_231_length_89097_cov_0.976280_72,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_9565_length_2974_cov_0.963826_2,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
>NODE_48_length_222468_cov_1.632467_203,301022,fa_12,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
```

The order of the first file changed and also there are `,,,,,` where there should be columns from second file. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Foreword

- Since you want to merge both dataframes by the `'id'` column (`>NODE...`), you should definitely use `df.merge`.
- As input files 1 and 2, I have used exactly what you provided.
- You need to use the input you provided, not the full data at your disposal. This makes mutual understanding difficult.
- "The order of the first file changed": This can be solved by sorting the resulting table.
- Finally, a quick look after formatting your question, and thus being able to read it, strongly suggests that your main problem is: you are not looking at the *out* files corresponding with your latest code. There is no way *out1.csv* and *out2.csv* would be identical.

---

### Reproducing problem

I started with reproducing your line `newdf = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='id')`. **What it does is complete `df1` with elements from `df2` found at the corresponding `'id'`, and leaves the rest of `df2` away**, thus returning only 3 rows. This is what it produces; *please confirm if this is what you seek or not.*

```py
newdf = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='id')

                                        id  sample    bin                                 profile                                             sub id                             identity              q length      alignment length           mismatches    gap opens                                  evalue             bit score
0  >NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10  301022  fa_10  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain                                     gb|AVX77188.1|                               67.177                   724                   719                  236            0                                     0.0                  1017
1  >NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104  301022  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain  gb|AGX66494.1|;gb|ADS15792.1|;gb|AKW57899.1|;g...  85.078;54.852;45.781;44.040;43.114;  518;518;518;518;518;  516;474;474;495;501;  77;204;231;246;258;  0;4;9;11;9;  0.0;0.0;1.47e-139;5.50e-138;1.69e-137;  928;557;416;413;411;
2   >NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20  301022  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain                                                NaN                                  NaN                   NaN                   NaN                  NaN          NaN                                     NaN                   NaN
```

Here as an exported csv, using your line `newdf.to_csv('out.txt', index=False)`:

```
id,sample,bin,profile,sub id,identity,q length,alignment length,mismatches,gap opens,evalue,bit score
>NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10,301022,fa_10,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,gb|AVX77188.1|,67.177,724,719,236,0,0.0,1017
>NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,gb|AGX66494.1|;gb|ADS15792.1|;gb|AKW57899.1|;gb|ACH26137.1|;gb|AGX66492.1|;,85.078;54.852;45.781;44.040;43.114;,518;518;518;518;518;,516;474;474;495;501;,77;204;231;246;258;,0;4;9;11;9;,0.0;0.0;1.47e-139;5.50e-138;1.69e-137;,928;557;416;413;411;
>NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20,301022,fa_11,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,,,,,,,,
```

The final `,,,,,,,,` indeed denotes `NaN`: `df2` had no information on `>NODE_793`

Is this your desired output?

What you post as *out1.csv* and *out2.csv* does not make sense:

- There is no way both would be identical
- It contains some 'id' that are not present in your posted input data
- There are repetitions of the same line
- I have no idea how you produced this file.

**Suggestion: it does not look like the result of a merge with df2 and you might have mixed up files and are not looking at the right csv. Please use different filenames when saving a new merge product.**

---

### About `set_index`

- `df1.set_index(['id'])` creates a view of df1 with index set. It does not change df1. To modify df1, use `df1.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)` instead.
- However merge works well on columns, so it's good that you didn't change the dataframes. **Your code works without it!** For more on this, see [Merge two dataframes by index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40468069/12846804)

---

### An alternative

Now in case you wanted to keep all information (merge **all** rows, not skip any row), then this is what you are looking for:

```
df1.merge(right=df2,
          how='outer', # 'outer' means keep all rows
          on='id',
          sort=True)   # optional, added just for readability

                                        id    sample    bin                                 profile                                             sub id                             identity              q length      alignment length            mismatches     gap opens                                          evalue             bit score
0  >NODE_102_length_146227_cov_1.193242_34       NaN    NaN                                     NaN  gb|AGD14055.1|;gb|QCA67811.1|;gb|QCA68885.1|;g...  49.512;40.618;40.047;41.734;38.038;  454;454;454;454;454;  410;421;422;369;418;  207;221;224;199;231;  0;10;10;8;8;  3.71e-159;1.64e-77;7.99e-76;4.89e-74;6.11e-70;  461;252;248;243;232;
1  >NODE_1045_length_25717_cov_0.952104_13       NaN    NaN                                     NaN  gb|AEI19864.1|;gb|QHZ14374.1|;gb|QFN56428.1|;g...  56.442;53.420;53.420;53.420;53.094;  372;372;372;372;372;  326;307;307;307;307;  140;142;142;142;143;    1;1;1;1;1;                                             NaN                   NaN
2  >NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10  301022.0  fa_10  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain                                     gb|AVX77188.1|                               67.177                   724                   719                   236             0                                             0.0                  1017
3   >NODE_793_length_32677_cov_0.985420_20  301022.0  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain                                                NaN                                  NaN                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN           NaN                                             NaN                   NaN
4  >NODE_84_length_160839_cov_0.924412_104  301022.0  fa_11  PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain  gb|AGX66494.1|;gb|ADS15792.1|;gb|AKW57899.1|;g...  85.078;54.852;45.781;44.040;43.114;  518;518;518;518;518;  516;474;474;495;501;   77;204;231;246;258;   0;4;9;11;9;          0.0;0.0;1.47e-139;5.50e-138;1.69e-137;  928;557;416;413;411;
```

Here the 5 `'id'` stay, with any relevant information from any of both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the row in the second file starting with (">NODE_1045_length_25717_cov_0.952104_13") has fewer columns than the rest. This may be due to the way it is displayed here ('\t' as a column separator is not ideal).

Try to explicitly set the column names when reading the file by for example:

```
df2_column_names = ['id', 'sub id', 'identity', 'q length', 'alignment length', 'mismatches', 'gap opens', 'evalue', 'bit score']
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2', sep='\t', names=df2_column_names)
```

Comment: When tried it only for df2 I got result with ,,,,,,. But when I tried for df1 and df2 I got correct result only for first string >NODE_1080_length_25086_cov_1.756193_10,301022,fa_10,PF00128-Alpha-amylase-catalytic-domain,gb|AVX77188.1|,67.177,724.0,719.0,236.0,0.0,0.0,1017.0 but also I see .0 after