# Pandas Dataframe concat: is it correct to understand append as a simplified version of concat with few kwargs and can only operate on axis=0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning about Merge and Join in pandas by reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append). It seems to me that `append` is just like the `concat`along axis = 0. And `concat`has more keyword arguments. For simple join/concatenation along axis = 0, are `append` and `concat` interchangeable?

And I have trouble understanding this sentence in the linked documentation about append:

> Note Unlike the append() method, which appends to the original list
>   and returns None, append() here does not modify df1 and returns its
>   copy with df2 appended.

I'm really confused by this sentence. It seems to be comparing `append()` to `append()`. which are identical. What did I miss here?

I am not sure if I can put my second question here. If it's against the rules, please let me know or help me edit the question.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: As for your second question, the reference was for the `append `method for `lists`, in contrast to the `append` method for `pd.DaraFrame`s. For `append`vs`concat`, might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819050/pandas-dataframe-concat-vs-append) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256104/differences-between-merge-and-concat-in-pandas)

Comment: @RafaelC Oh that certainly cleared things up for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `pd.append` simply calls `pd.concat` with the default arguments `axis=0, join='outer'` which you can see in the `return` statement. It also has limited functionality, so you can't use it to construct a hierarchical index.

[`pd.append source`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L6204-L6211)

> ```
>     from pandas.core.reshape.concat import concat
>     if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)):
>         to_concat = [self] + other
>     else:
>         to_concat = [self, other]
>     return concat(to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index,
>                   verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
>                   sort=sort)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and link. But would you care to elaborate how this source code is about pd.append since there seemingly is no part denoting "append"? If possible, could you help me explain what `other` means and does in the code please? Thanks again.

Comment: @BowenLiu Sure. I just copied a small part of the `append` function. The full function is highlighted [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L6075-L6211), with the last few lines above being the return statement for `pd.append`. If you look at the full source code you can see that if you call `df.append(df1)`, then `df` is treated as `self` and `other` will reference `df1`, the `DataFrame` or `Series` to append. So `to_concat` is basically just a list of the `DataFrames`, `[df, df1]`, which is passed to `pd.concat`