# Trying to merge 2 dataframes but get ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

These are my two dataframes saved in two variables:

```
> print(df.head())
>
          club_name  tr_jan  tr_dec  year
    0  ADO Den Haag    1368    1422  2010
    1  ADO Den Haag    1455    1477  2011
    2  ADO Den Haag    1461    1443  2012
    3  ADO Den Haag    1437    1383  2013
    4  ADO Den Haag    1386    1422  2014
> print(rankingdf.head())
>
           club_name  ranking  year
    0    ADO Den Haag    12    2010
    1    ADO Den Haag    13    2011
    2    ADO Den Haag    11    2012
    3    ADO Den Haag    14    2013
    4    ADO Den Haag    17    2014
```

I'm trying to merge these two using this code:

```
new_df = df.merge(ranking_df, on=['club_name', 'year'], how='left')
```

The how='left' is added because I have less datapoints in my ranking_df than in my standard df.

The expected behaviour is as such:

```
> print(new_df.head()) 
> 

      club_name  tr_jan  tr_dec  year    ranking
0  ADO Den Haag    1368    1422  2010    12
1  ADO Den Haag    1455    1477  2011    13
2  ADO Den Haag    1461    1443  2012    11
3  ADO Den Haag    1437    1383  2013    14
4  ADO Den Haag    1386    1422  2014    17
```

But I get this error:

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

But I do not wish to use concat since I want to merge the trees not just add them on.

Another behaviour that's weird in my mind is that my code works if I save the first df to .csv and then load that .csv into a dataframe.

The code for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_points, columns=['club_name', 'tr_jan', 'tr_dec', 'year'])
df.to_csv('preliminary.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('preliminary.csv', index_col=0)

ranking_df = pd.DataFrame(rankings, columns=['club_name', 'ranking', 'year'])

new_df = df.merge(ranking_df, on=['club_name', 'year'], how='left')
```

I think that it has to do with the index_col=0 parameter. But I have no idea to fix it without having to save it, it doesn't matter much but is kind of an annoyance that I have to do that.

Comment: Got the same error when i have used join instead of merge.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

In one of your dataframes the year is a string and the other it is an int64
you can convert it first and then join  (e.g. `df['year']=df['year'].astype(int)` or as RafaelC suggested `df.year.astype(int)`)

Edit: Also note the comment by Anderson Zhu: Just in case you have `None` or missing values in one of your dataframes, you need to use `Int64` instead of `int`. See the reference [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Kinda weird since I saved every year as ints.

Comment: why not `df.year.astype(int)`?

Comment: I did eventually fix it in another way, just saved all year variables into the data-frame as integers. Never figured they were strings.

Comment: @RafaelC that's probably better

Comment: Hi I used below code import pandas as pd
df1  = pd.read_excel(r" ")
df2  = pd.read_excel(r" ")
df2['changerequestnumber']=df2['changerequestnumber'].astype(int)
f9=df1.merge(df3, left_on='Related CRs', right_on='changerequestnumber')
f9.to_excel(r" ") but still i am getting ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int32 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
can you help me on this

Comment: Just in case you have None or missing values in one of your dataframes, you need to use `Int64` instead of `int`. See the reference [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: @PEREZje, it works when you import from csv because the csv is making everything into  strings. So, you are then comparing strings to strings. Similarly, when you import from csv, even though you entered it as int, it was converted to a string. You have to convert it back.

Comment: Even after doing this, the issue was not resolved. In the end, I used pd.merge only.

Answer (score 167):

I found that my dfs both had the same type column (`str`) but switching from `join` to `merge` solved the issue.

Comment: Same here. If somebody knows why, please write below :)

Comment: Same. Very odd indeed, my only guess is that even if everything is of type `object`, when doing the join pandas tries to evaluate data types once more implicitly... But merge solved it for me too.

Comment: @raummensch and @15Step, I had the same problem. The reason for why merge works on strings but join doesn't can be found in the answer by @MatthiasFripp here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676081/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-merge-in-pandas). Basically ```df1.join(df2)``` always merges via the index of ```df2``` whereas ```df1.merge(df2)``` will merge on the column. So basically we were trying to merge based off a string and an integer, even though both columns were strings..

Comment: This happened with me too. Thanks for telling us.

Comment: Every 6 months I find my way back to this answer after forgetting this trick lol, thanks Alex!

Answer (score 6):

It happens when common column in both table are of different data type.

Example: In table1, you have **date** as string whereas in table2 you have **date** as datetime. so before merging,we need to change **date** to common data type.

Answer (score 4):

@Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz answer is right for the most part. But I would like to point out the difference between `df['year']=df['year'].astype(int)` and `df.year.astype(int)`. `df.year.astype(int)` returns a view of the dataframe and doesn't not explicitly change the type, atleast in pandas 0.24.2. `df['year']=df['year'].astype(int)` explicitly change the type because it's an assignment. I would argue that this is the safest way to permanently change the dtype of a column.

Example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Weed': ['green crack', 'northern lights', 'girl scout 
                            cookies'], 'Qty':[10,15,3]})
df.dtypes`

> Weed    object,
>   Qty      int64

`df['Qty'].astype(str)
 df.dtypes`

> Weed    object,
>   Qty      int64

Even setting the inplace arg to True doesn't help at times. I don't know why this 
happens though. In most cases inplace=True equals an explicit assignment.

`df['Qty'].astype(str, inplace = True)
 df.dtypes`

> Weed    object,
>   Qty      int64

Now the assignment,

`df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].astype(str)
df.dtypes`

> Weed    object,
>   Qty     object

Comment: As of `pandas` 1.2.4, `Series.astype` doesn't have an `inplace` argument. It has a `copy` argument, which might behave in the same way but I haven't tested.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it happened because I was trying to merge columns that where not the index, so in order to fix this I used this code that I found in the documentation:

```
df.set_index('key').join(other.set_index('key'))
```

Documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html
 [set key to be the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 2):

At first check the type of columns which you want to merge. You will see one of them is string where other one is `int`. Then convert it to int as following code:

```
df["something"] = df["something"].astype(int)

merged = df.merge[df1, on="something"]
```

Comment: This works, but is giving a `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame...`

Answer (score 1):

Additional: when you save df to .csv format, the datetime (year in this specific case) is saved as object, so you need to convert it into integer (year in this specific case) when you do the merge. That is why when you upload both df from csv files, you can do the merge easily, while above error will show up if one df is uploaded from csv files and the other is from an existing df. This is somewhat annoying, but have an easy solution if kept in mind.

Answer (score 0):

this simple solution works for me

```
    final = pd.concat([df, rankingdf], axis=1, sort=False)
```

but you may need to drop some duplicate column first.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I had the same issue and could not see why I was getting that because when doing
`data.head()` I saw the exact same values in `ds` (time column).

The error was fixed when I added `parse_dates` in the `pd.read_csv()` function. This way:

```
data = pd.read_csv(('source.csv'), sep=';', parse_dates=['Date'], encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue as I was only trying to merge 2 data-frames. In my scenario, both datasets are almost identical, except 2 extra columns.
Hence I was following your solution.

```
def merge_dataframe(df1, df2, mode, column_name: any, col_chng: str):
    """
    :param df1: dataframe as str
    :param df2: dataframe as str
    :param mode: str
    :param column_name: any
    :param col_chng:
    :return:
    """
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

    os.chdir(output_dir)
    if column_name is None:
        new_df = df1.merge(df2, how=mode)
    else:
        df1[column_name] = df2[column_name].astype(col_chng)
        new_df = df1.merge(df2, on=column_name, how=mode)
    new_df.to_excel('new_df.xlsx', index=False)
```

Hope, this will help others. Kindly correct me, if I'm missing something.