# How can I merge two data sets of different lengths in Python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have tried merging with Pandas merge, however, as the length of data is different, merge function is broadcasting the data even when using a key.
The following line of code has been used.

```
dt = pd.merge(df,data[['Post ID','Sentiment']], on = 'Post ID')
```

Using `join` produces the following:

```
df.join(data[['Post ID','Sentiment']],on = 'Post ID')
```

> You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to merge 2 dataframes but get ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649853/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-get-valueerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that in one of your database, `Post ID` is an `object`and in the other one it is defined as `int`.
You need to convert them so they have the same type, for instance by doing :

```
df['Post ID'] = df['Post ID'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I have tried changing the post ID type to string as Post ID contains both strings and integers. However, the error persists

Comment: Could you provide data so we can reproduce your error ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide the data as it is from a client.