# Pandas Join on String Datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join two pandas dataframes on an id field which is a string uuid. I get a Value error:

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

The code is below. I am trying to convert the fields to string as per [Trying to merge 2 dataframes but get ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649853/trying-to-merge-2-dataframes-but-get-valueerror/50649933) but the error remains. Note that pdf is coming from a spark `dataframe.toPandas()` while outputsPdf is created from a dictionary.

```
pdf.id = pdf.id.apply(str)
outputsPdf.id = outputsPdf.id.apply(str)
inOutPdf = pdf.join(outputsPdf, on='id', how='left', rsuffix='fs')

pdf.dtypes
id         object
time      float64
height    float32
dtype: object

outputsPdf.dtypes
id         object
labels    float64
dtype: object
```

How can I debug this?
Full Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-deb429dde9ad> in <module>()
     61 pdf['id'] = pdf['id'].astype(str)
     62 outputsPdf['id'] = outputsPdf['id'].astype(str)
---> 63 inOutPdf = pdf.join(outputsPdf, on=['id'], how='left', rsuffix='fs')
     64 
     65 # idSparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(idPandasDf, schema=StructType([StructField('id', StringType(), True),

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   6334         # For SparseDataFrame's benefit
   6335         return self._join_compat(other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix,
-> 6336                                  rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
   6337 
   6338     def _join_compat(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   6349             return merge(self, other, left_on=on, how=how,
   6350                          left_index=on is None, right_index=True,
-> 6351                          suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
   6352         else:
   6353             if on is not None:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     59                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     60                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
---> 61                          validate=validate)
     62     return op.get_result()
     63 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    553         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
    554         # to avoid incompat dtypes
--> 555         self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
    556 
    557         # If argument passed to validate,

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
    984             elif (not is_numeric_dtype(lk)
    985                     and (is_numeric_dtype(rk) and not is_bool_dtype(rk))):
--> 986                 raise ValueError(msg)
    987             elif is_datetimelike(lk) and not is_datetimelike(rk):
    988                 raise ValueError(msg)
```

Comment: Please can you show the full traceback for this?

Comment: There has to be some NaN values in them, could you print pdf.loc[pdf['id'].isna(), 'id'], and ouputsPdf.loc[outputsPdf['id'].isna(), 'id']?

Comment: a `dtype` of `object` for a column does not mean it's a `string` column. It's simply a container for mixed types, including strings. `pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, True, 4]})` will have `dtype = object` for the `id` column, yet `type(df.id[0])` is `int` and `type(df.id[1])` is `bool`.

Comment: @thelogicalkoan I have run list(pdf.loc[pdf['id'].isna(), 'id']) which returns an empty array. Doesn't seem to be a NaN issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `on` parameter **only applies to the calling DataFrame**!

> `on`: Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other, otherwise joins index-on-index.

Though you specify `on='id'` it will use the `'id'` in pdf, which is an object and attempt to join that with the index of outputsPdf, which takes integer values.

If you need to `join` on non-index columns across two DataFrames you can either set them to the index, or you must use `merge` as the `on` paremeter in `pd.merge` applies to **both** DataFrames.

---

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', 'True', '4'], 'vals': [10, 11, 12]})
df2 = df1.copy()

df1.join(df2, on='id', how='left', rsuffix='_fs')
```

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

On the other hand, these work:

```
df1.set_index('id').join(df2.set_index('id'), how='left', rsuffix='_fs').reset_index()
#     id  vals  vals_fs
#0     1    10       10
#1  True    11       11
#2     4    12       12

df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', suffixes=['', '_fs'])
#     id  vals  vals_fs
#0     1    10       10
#1  True    11       11
#2     4    12       12
```