# How can these two dataframes be merged on a specific key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes, both with a column `'hotelCode'` that is type string. I made sure to convert both columns to string beforehand.

The first dataframe, we'll call `old_DF` looks like so:

[image]

and the second dataframe `new_DF` looks like:

[image]

I have been trying to merge these unsuccessfully. I've tried

```
final_DF = new_DF.join(old_DF, on = 'hotelCode')
```

and get this error:

[image]

I've tried a variety of things: changing the index name, various merge/join/concat and just haven't been successful.

Ideally, I will have a new dataframe where you have columns `[[hotelCode, oldDate, newDate]]` under one roof.

Comment: I think you're having exactly the same problem found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373285/pandas-join-on-string-datatype. Does the `merge` solution work, though a `merge` will grow this DataFrame a lot. Do you need to merge on the index **and** hotelCode? or simply concat?

Comment: can you show the output of `old_df.hotelCode.head()` and `new_df.hotelCode.head()`?

Comment: you should ensure the columns have the same variable type before merging the dataframes. But I'm confused how a column with values like "ALFTBW" could  possibly be an int64 type in one of your dataframes (hence my question above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

final_DF = pd.merge(old_DF, new_DF, on='hotelCode', how='outer')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much