# Python join two frames with one common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have in python frame A

[image]

and frame B:

[image]

How can I Add new column 'name' in frame A in order to display the column z value from the frame b? The common columns between the two frames are `A['b']` and `B['v']`

I'm trying with pandas concat or merge but i'm failing.

The expected result in frame A I would have is:

[image]

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards
Giancarlo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between join and merge in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676081/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-merge-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your merge failing? It should work on a `left` join with A as left and specifying the `left_on` and `right_on` columns:

```
final_output = A.merge(B,how='left',left_on='b',right_on='v').rename(columns={'z':'name'}).drop(columns='v')
```

Output:

```
     a  b    c     d   name
0  Yes  1  Yes   Buy  name1
1  Yes  2  Yes  Sell  name2
2  Yes  3  Yes   Buy  name3
3  Yes  4  Yes  Sell  name4
```